# Origin of street names ending in "-hurst"

Tags: meaning, etymology, proper-nouns, toponyms

There is a large number of streets in the UK whose names end in *-hurst*, for example *Ravenhurst, Gathurst, Oakhurst, Amhurst, Bonehurst, Eaglehurst*, etc.

Is there a common meaning for this *-hurst* ending? How old are these names?

Comment: sweet question, especially for anyone who ever lived in Darlinghurst!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[One reference](http://www.localhistories.org/names.html): *hurst* = wooded hill. In **street** names, it's likely to be a modern invention; in **place** names, it may well survive from antiquity.

It's a Saxon word, and would thus probably occur more in Southern England than the Danelaw in the north. OED has

> Etymology:  Old English *hyrst* < Old Germanic type **hursti-z*, whence Old High German, Middle High German *hurst,* German dialect *horst* ‘heap, cluster, thicket, top of rock, sandbank’ (Flügel); Middle Low German *horst* hill, wooded or bushy eminence, small wood, Low German *horst, host,* a bushy piece of land surrounded with marsh, a wooded eminence, East Frisian *hörst, horst, höst,* thicket, copse, sandy eminence (probably formerly overgrown with brushwood); Middle Dutch *horst* (Kilian *horscht, horst*) thicket of brushwood. In the forms *-hurst, -hirst, -herst,* a frequent element in place-names, as in *Hawkhurst, Chislehurst, Ferniehirst, Amherst.* (So *-horst* in Dutch and Low German.)
>
> Icelandic *hrjóstr* rough place, barren rocky place, Norwegian dialect *rust, ryst,* little wood, thicket, clump of alders and dwarf birch, wooded tract on a mountain, lateral ridge of a mountain, Faroese *rust* ridge, show similarity of sense, but are difficult to connect phonologically.

Comment: Thank you! The link is very interesting :) it answers huge amount of my questions.

Comment: Henry Bathurst, 3rd Earl Bathurst (1762-1834) got several places named after him: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Bathurst,_3rd_Earl_Bathurst

Answer (score 4):

*Hurst* appears to mean a wooded hill according to [this site](http://www.localhistories.org/names.html).  It is an old part of a name but only local research could tell you whether a road was ancient or had just been given a name made up from old roots to imbue a sense of history and rootedness.

Answer (score 1):

*Hurst* (and also *hirst* and sometimes corrupted over time to *est*) comes from the Old English *hyrst* which could mean a copse, a hill or both; a hill with a copse on it.

In English names then, it suggests an origin prior to the Battle of Hastings and the coming of the Normans, though the existence of such names in America and Australia should be enough to demonstrate that it's possible for somewhere with that name to have been founded after 1066, and just named in imitation of the form used elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood it, and was told as a small child, "Hurst" was a small clearing (smaller than a field or meadow), generally along side a body of water, like a river or lake. I was also told that "Hyrst" is the stone below and what the mill stone/"grindstone" travels in to crush/grind the grain.
Even here in the U.S. (across the "pond" as some might say) there are many place names and different spellings attached to "Hurst". Michael Jackson lived at 4641 "Hayvenhurst" Ave. in the San Fernando Valley and there is a "Havenhurst" Street and Apartment complex in Hollywood. 
I believe that the British Military Academy is located at "Sandhurst" which would sort of contradict some of the other "sandy" definitions I have read. I understand there are many other variations of spellings and definitions too. 
There is a city in Texas named "Hurst" (and an auto transmission company). I like the "Urban Dictionary's" definition but have no idea how they got that...

Comment: Thank you for your information. I suppose I would cite "oral history" as my sourcing in how I understand this word and as was told to me by my father as he was told by his father and so forth. There is a "FairHURST" Hall located near Parbold in England. I have also had the definition I understand confirmed by others (being an unusual last name) with others sharing this surname whom have a tendency to contact those with that same surname while in travel (general verbal confirmation?). However, I would suppose that a true definition is in the usage of that language and of those words within it.